# Updating/modifying Network Dataset roads source in Enterprise Geodatabase (ArcSDE) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am trying to create a Python script that automate the update of roads source used in a network dataset stored in a Enterprise Geodatabase (SDE). In short, I want to truncate the roads feature class and append the new roads data into it without have to recreate the network dataset.

When I try to edit the roads feature class, I encounter an error because arcpy can't edit a feature class used by a network dataset outside an edit session.

I tried using an update cursor in an edit session but I get `RuntimeError: workspace already in transaction mode`

```
import arcpy, os, time
time1 = time.time()

ROADS_INPUT = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "Geobase", "GEO03_ADDRESS.gdb", "GEO03_ADDRESS", "GEO03E08_ROADS")
WORKSPACE = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "ArcGIS Server", "Connections", "Enterprise.sde")
ROADS_NA = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "ArcGIS Server", "Connections", "Enterprise.sde", "NA", "ROADS_2018_04")

editSession = arcpy.da.Editor(WORKSPACE)
editSession.startEditing(False, True)
editSession.startOperation()

#truncating the NA roads table
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ROADS_NA, field_names="*") as u_cursor:
    for row in u_cursor:
        cursor.deleteRow()

#inserting rows from input to NA roads
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(ROADS_INPUT, field_names="*") as s_cursor:
    with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(ROADS_NA, field_names="*") as i_cursor:
        for row in s_cursor:
            i_cursor.insertRow(row)

editSession.stopOperation()
editSession.stopEditing(True)
time2 = time.time()
print "script took {:.3f} ms".format((time2-time1)*1000.0)
```

Is there a strategy I could try to achieve what I am trying to do?

Note: The network dataset is stored in Enterprise Geodatabase (SDE)

**EDIT:**

Using `arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management()` and `arcpy.Append_management()` instead of cursors results in `error 99999 Objects in this class cannot be updated outside and edit session [Enterprise.ROADS_2018_04]`

```
import arcpy, os, time
time1 = time.time()

ROADS_INPUT = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "Geobase", "GEO03_ADDRESS.gdb", "GEO03_ADDRESS", "GEO03E08_ROADS")
WORKSPACE = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "ArcGIS Server", "Connections", "Enterprise.sde")
ROADS_NA = os.path.join(r"\\dd734dd", "geo", "ArcGIS Server", "Connections", "Enterprise.sde", "NA", "ROADS_2018_04")

editSession = arcpy.da.Editor(WORKSPACE)
editSession.startEditing(False, True)
editSession.startOperation()

arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management(ROADS_NA)
arcpy.Append_management(ROADS_INPUT, ROADS_NA)

editSession.stopOperation()
editSession.stopEditing(True)
time2 = time.time()
print "script took {:.3f} ms".format((time2-time1)*1000.0)
```

Comment: What happens when you kill the locks on the SDE and then try?

Comment: I see locks but I cant kill them from the ArcCatalog dialog box

Comment: Ok the locks were created by PyScripter. After closing it, I launch the script in cmd but I got the same workspace already in transaction mode error

Comment: Hmm ... that is strange then.  let me ask around here at work and see if anyone may know.

Comment: Why are you using cursors? Surely it would be quicker to use DeleteFeatures https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000036000000 on a layer made with a where_clause then use Append https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000 to add the new objects to your feature class. From your code you're deleting **all of the roads** is that *really* what you want to do?

Comment: @MichaelStimson That's not the issue for this question.

Comment: You did ask *"Is there a strategy I could try to achieve what I am trying to do?"*, as this feature class participates in a network you will still need to start editing/operation and stop operation/editing then Build Network https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00480000000v000000 on the Network Dataset to reestablish connectivity.

Comment: As mentionned in the question, there is an error doing so. I tried using `arcpy.DeleteFeatures_management` and `arcpy.Append_management` (see edited question) but there is an error too

Answer (score 1):

What I have found so far, is that a Network Dataset can only be updated by creating a new version, and the Network dataset metadata is updated when the version are made Default.
So you must use versioning.
If the resulting Network dataset are to be consumed by ie an Closes Facility Service from ArcGIS Server, it could be a solution for you creating a complete new Network dataset, then change the source from the old to the new Network dataset, then republish and later drop the old dataset. A bit messy, but it works.